# Getting a "Value Error:", no clue how to resolve it - Python 3.4

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a program that reads lines from a test file (coordinates.txt) and sets every other line to (x,y). It's running how it should, but giving me an error when it's done executing.

Here is a pastie of everything: http://pastie.org/10503111

Comment: oh, BTW congrats for getting 100k. Go ask and collect the swag.

Comment: @trev915: If you add `print(repr(x), repr(y))` after you read them you should see the problem.

Comment: Please **edit** your question and *paste your code here*, **don't** use a *third party website*

Comment: @DSM That didn't resolve the error unfortunately.

Comment: @trev915: ... yes, adding a `print` won't fix the problem.  It helps you *recognize* the problem.  What it will show you is what `x` and `y` *are*, not what you *thought they would be*-- that's how debugging works.

Comment: @DSM what do you think about changing line 13 to: `while line.strip():` ?

Comment: @DSM Surprisingly, it prints what I expected it would. '100' '200', so on so forth for the rest. No actual strings.

Comment: @trev915 But what does it print just before the error? The only one that matters here is the *last* one: the one that fails.

Comment: @HenryKeiter The last thing it prints is '100' '300' just like that.

Comment: I know posting screenshots from a third party website is frowned upon, but this may be very useful to help solve my issue. Here is the output: https://gyazo.com/ae3d3177185e6dd445e31d0e9f480fc7

Comment: @trev915 You've got your `print` in the wrong place. You need to put it *right* after you set `x` and `y`. It's currently showing you the iteration *before* the one that breaks. I know, because I'd bet my hat that when you put the `print` in the right spot, you'll see that it's trying to convert `'\n'` or `''` to a float.

Comment: @HenryKeiter You were right! I added .strip() to the end of it to get rid of the '\n' and I'm STILL getting an error... Screenshot: https://gyazo.com/5f1e0615ff54352c411dd2c1c369b5f4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that the readline function keeps the '\n' (new line character) at the end of the line. You can probably fix this by using an array index for the string variable. For example, float(x[:-1]) will omit the newline character at the end of the string and get rid of your error.

**Correction**
Try this code:

```
x = file.readline().strip()
y = file.readline().strip()
while (x != '' and y != ''):
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.setpos(float(x), float(y))
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.dot(10)
    x = file.readline().strip()
    y = file.readline().strip()
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the OP's problem (`float()` ignores whitespace already), and you should use `strip()` to remove whitespace in any case.

Comment: This is exactly what I've been trying to do. You seemed to do it better. BUT, for some reason, the first two lines get skipped which causes one whole coordinate to not be plotted.

Comment: Are you sure you are not reading any lines in previous lines of your program?

Comment: I feel silly. My print was in the wrong location. It was at the very end of my while statement.

Answer (score 0):

You're either trying to convert a newline character or an empty string (or some other whitespace) to a float. You have two related issues (and another bug) at play:

1. You never change the value of `line`, so your loop will never terminate.
2. Even if you were setting `line` the way you think you are, your `while` loop only checks the very next line, but you then try to read *two* lines on each iteration. If you have an odd number of lines, you're toast (because the last line will check out okay, but then you'll try to read *another* line past that, and you'll blow up).
3. Your loop (when fixed) will ensure that the next line you read isn't strictly empty, *but* it could still contain whitespace characters (such as `'\n'`, the newline character) that can't be converted. To check if you've got a useful line, you could try `while line.strip():` for your loop instead. That way you'd stop as soon as you get to an empty (or semantically empty) line.

---

But all of this is sort of a silly, longhanded way to solve the problem. A better way would probably be to embrace `readlines()` to make a list of all the lines in the file, and then process them without worrying about file IO getting in the way of your logic.

```
all_lines = file.readlines()  # Nice list of all the lines in the file.
# Now do whatever you want with your easily-accessible lines of text.
```

Comment: How would I make it work with an odd number of lines? (It has to.)

Comment: If I were you, I'd make sure that *each time* I read a line, the content was useful.

Comment: This is for an assignment in my class, one of the use cases requires there to be an even number of integers for (X,Y) valus in the file. I believe the reason for the error is that there is an even number. How would I get it to work? I tried the while line.strip(): loop and it still produces the error.

Comment: @trev915 Your first problem is that your loop never terminates (#1 in my answer). Your other problems are also addressed.

Comment: How exactly would I make that work, though? To set every pair of two coordinates to (x,y). Also, not asking for someone to do my assignment, I'm asking for help, which I believe I'm in the right place for.

Comment: @trev915 That's a whole other question. I'd probably make two lists of numbers, then process the first item in each list, then the second, and so on until you're done.